# Cannot change identity of an already logged in user in realm

Tags: android, authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I tried an offline authentication demo application which can be found here:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-topics/offline-authentication/

I have a problem with the adapter invocation.
In `onlineAuthentication()`, `myCustomRealmChallengeHandler.submitAdapterAuthentication` fails.
I even add a logout before, and I have this error message on the server:

> FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure [project
>   OfflineAuthentication]authenticationAdapter/submitAuthentication
>   FWLSE0100E: parameters: [project OfflineAuthentication] Cannot change
>   identity of an already logged in user in realm 'xxxxxx'.  The
>   application must logout first.

On client after logout, `wl.client.isUserAuthenticated` is false.
I also tried a `WLAuthorizationManager.getUserIdentity()` to know if the adapter must do the `setActiveUser`.

**In the main.js:**

```
   

WL.Client.logout("spgRealm", {onSuccess:logoutSuccess, onFailure:logoutFailure});
WLAuthorizationManager.getUserIdentity().then(function(){

    var invocationData = {

        adapter : "authenticationAdapter",
        procedure : "submitAuthentication",
        parameters : [$("#usr").val(), $("#pwd").val(), usrInfo.sid, true ]
    };

    alert('sans ecran login '+JSON.stringify(invocationData));
    spgRCH.submitAdapterAuthentication( invocationData, {

        onSuccess:onlineAuthenticationSuccess, 
        onFailure:onlineAuthenticationFailure 
    });
})
```

**In the adapter:**

```
function submitAuthentication(username, password, sid, isIdentified){
    var i = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : '/mobapp/auth.php',
        parameters :  {'USR' : username, 'PWD' : password, 'SID' : sid}
    };
    var o = WL.Server.invokeHttp(i);

    if (isIdentified == false) {

        var userIdentity = {
            userId: username,
            displayName: username, 
            attributes: { 'mobile' : true }
        };

        WL.Server.setActiveUser("spgRealm", userIdentity);
    }
    return { 

        authRequired: false,
        'httprsp' : o 
    };

    return onAuthRequired(null, "SRVE001");
}
```

**I also try:**

```
WL.Server.setActiveUser("spgRealm", null);
```

However, the result is an infinite loop.

I test with Android Studio and an Android application.

the case:
First, logging-in on-line, 
Second, quit secure area without logout
third, logging-in off-line
then access secure area on-line with user store off-line
the authentication failed.

the error :

> FWLSE0100E: parameters: [project OfflineAuthentication] Cannot change
>   identity of an already logged in user in realm 'xxxxxx'.  The
>   application must logout first.

the problem is in this part of code (main.js) :

```
// If logging-in while offline and Internet connectivity is then available, login to the realm without showing the login form.
} else if (username) {
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : "authenticationAdapter",
        procedure : "submitAuthentication",
        parameters : [$("#username").val(), $("#password").val()]
    };

    myCustomRealmChallengeHandler.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, {
        onSuccess:onlineAuthenticationSuccess,
        onFailure:onlineAuthenticationFailure 
    });
```

Comment: I decided to change the authentication method and work differently by inspiring me of another tutorial.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to comment in more detail on what you did to resolve this issue, or what other tutorial you referenced to solve it?

Comment: @Sébastien, please see pat's question above. Can you write an Answer for this question?